# JavaScript | Spread operator update nested value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I am trying to update a nested value of an object using the spread operator. This is my first time using this and I believe I am pretty close to achieving my end goal but I just can't seem to figure out what I actually need to do next.

I have an array which is structured like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "Category 1",
        posts: [
            {
                id: 1,
                published: false,
                category: "Category 1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                published: true,
                category: "Category 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Category 2",
        posts: [
            {
                id: 3,
                published: true,
                category: "Category 2"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                published: true,
                category: "Category 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

On the click of a button I am trying to update the published value, and as I am using React I need to set the state. So it got recommended to me that I update using the spread operator.

```
onPostClick(post) {
    post.pubished = !post.published;
    this.setState({...this.state.posts[post.category], post})
}
```

If I log out the result of `{...this.state.posts[post.category], post}` I can see that the published is getting added to the parent which forms:

```
{
    name: "Category 1",
    published: false,
    posts: [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Obviously this isn't the intended result, I want it to update the actual object within the `posts` object.

I have tried to do something like `this.setState({...this.state.posts[post.category].posts, post})` but I get a message that it is undefined.

Comment: `onPostClick(post)` - what is post format, does it contain full data together with id / category etc. ?

Comment: The format is `{ id: 1, category: 'Category 1', published: true }`

Comment: So yes @Goran.it it contains all of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access your data with `this.state.posts[post.category]`. `posts` data in the objects of the array.

You can make a filter to find your category object in array and change its posts value.

```
onPostClick(post) {
    //CLONE YOUR DATA
    var postArray = this.state.posts;

    //FIND YOUR CATEGORY OBJECT IN ARRAY
    var categoryIndex = postArray.findIndex(function(obj){
        return obj.name === post.category;
    });

    //FIND YOUR POST AND CHANGE PUBLISHED VALUE
    postArray[categoryIndex].posts.forEach(function(item){
       if (item.id === post.id) {
           item.published = !item.published;
       } 
    });
    //SET TO STATE TO RERENDER
    this.setState({ posts: postArray});
}
```

This should work if your name of the state is true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Before I try this, I just wanted to ask. How come you opted for a `for ()` loop rather than `.forEach` ? Is there a reason for this or is it personal preference?

Comment: @connormiotk96 that came to my mind first. Updated with forEach.

Comment: @connormiotk96 what's wrong with for loop? i think you get more flexibility with the length in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

just adding, we know there are many ways to succeed, maybe you also want to try this way too..

```
onPostClick = post => {
    let published = this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
      item.posts.map((item_post, i) => {
        if (item_post.category === post.category) {
          item_post.published = !post.published;
        }
      });
    });
    this.setState({ ...this.state.data, published });
 };
```